# Ruby on Railsでjqueryのバージョンを2.xにしたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, jquery-ui

Gemfileで
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 3.1.0'
としてbundle updateとかbundle installとかやってみたんですがjQueryのバージョンが1.11.1のままになってるみたいなんです。
jquery.jsで
 * jQuery JavaScript Library v1.11.1
となってるし、
puts Jquery::Rails::JQUERY_VERSION
も1.11.1になったままです。
なんかそもそものやり方を間違えているんでしょうか？
（だったとしたら検索してわからないのも当然なので皆さんのアドバイスを！）
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jquery-rails gem](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails) の Installation のところにも書いてありますが、`application.js`の

```
//= require jquery
```

を、

```
//= require jquery2
```

にしてください。

なお、jquery2 のバージョンは、`Jquery::Rails::JQUERY_2_VERSION`で分かりますが、どちらのjqueryを`require`しているかは、`application.js`を見るしかないと思います。

Comment: 結構大変でしたが rails を 4.2 にアップグレードしてから jquery-rails 4.0.2 をインストールしたのちに、上記方法でうまくいきました。ありがとうございました。